# Boeing 777 MHA370

Tags: safety, accidents, boeing

Can anyone explain how a Boeing 777-200 can vanish without a trace?

How can it simply disappear without any indication of an in-flight emergency from the flight crew?

Does its disappearance and lack of any physical evidence suggest a catastrophic in-flight emergency which unfolded so rapidly that it caught the flight crew off guard and unable to send a distress signal?

Is it possible for someone other than the flight crew to disable its transponder or alter its radar signature to render it undetectable?

Comment: *"is that mean that If got bad or emergency happen in the plane and if its very fast one there's no chance that the pilot can ask for help first?"*  I do not even know what that is supposed to mean?

Comment: hypothetically if a bomb exploded under your seat you won't be able to signal ATC about it, otherwise it's a dupe